# Che vuol dire "arrepezzato"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Parlano – con dialetti diversi e a volte incomprensibili – di incazzature, mazzate, duemila pezze che Agnello deve consegnare a qualcuno altrimenti gli mozzano il naso e glielo ficcano su per il sedere, cosí la sentirà veramente la puzza al naso, quello sparagnino arricchito e **arrepezzato**.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "arrepezzato" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo e neanche "arrepezzare" in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine napoletana?

Comment: In dialetto genovese “u repessin” è lo straccivendolo, il robivecchi. Per estensione in Liguria diciamo che un uomo è repessito quando è trasandato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In questo [vocabolario di dialetto napoletano](https://www.liberoricercatore.it/vocabolario-dialettale/) ho trovato:

> **arrepezzate** 
> rattoppato, ma in un senso più enfatico, a significare un
> riaggiustamento fatto alla buona

Nel contesto da te citato vuol significare che quello sparagnino arricchito è comunque un personaggio con le pezze al sedere.